# Why can't an anonymous class have static members (other than final ones) in Java?

Tags: java, anonymous-class

[Anonymous classes cannot have any static members except for those that are constant.](https://www.baeldung.com/java-anonymous-classes#2-static-members)
Static members belong to a class and not individual instances. So, static memebers should be allowed in an anonymous class as the class cannot have multiple instances.

Comment: So by your assertion "the class cannot have multiple instances", so in that case, what's the need for `static`?

Comment: Anonymous classes are not allowed static members other than *compile-time constants*, whose values are effectively inlined into the compiled code, so they're essentially not there at all.

Answer (score 0):

`as the class cannot have multiple instances.`

It surely can !

Live example :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AnonymousTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Runnable> runnables = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            final int id = i;
            runnables.add(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Hello ! " + id);
                }
            });
        }
        runnables.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
AnonymousTest$1@58372a00
AnonymousTest$1@4dd8dc3
AnonymousTest$1@6d03e736
```

As you can see, an AnonymousTest can have many instances ! Here we have three different.

A constraint with Anonymous Classes is that they must live after the lifecycle of the instance that created them. So, they need to copy all outer variables which is why you need them final.